# iOS stops moving apps to suspended state in iOS 13.5.1(Keeps running in the background)

Tags: ios, swift, lifecycle, xcode11

I did a little bit more tests today.
And I found that iOS does not really suspend the app while it's in the background state anymore.
Here's how I test it.

```
while(true){
    napLock.wait(timeout: .now() + napDelay)
    looperLog.i("running")
}
```

It's running on a worker thread.
When the app is in the background state, the iOS will suspend all activities of this app before iOS 13.5.
So there should be no more logs in the console.
But after several switching between the foreground state and background state, iOS stops moving this app to the suspended state, so the app keeps running in the background.
I think that's why there are so many apps showing a long running background activities in the battery usage page.
Because all the apps are in background state rather than suspended state, so the system sees them as running in the background.
I haven't migrated to the new `UISceneDelegate`, so I'm still using `AppDelegate` to manage window and transitions.
If there's some new features about it, shouldn't be applied to my app.
This kind of thing changed the whole lifecycle, but there's nothing about it in the release notes.
Is there a new implementation while the app entering the background state?
How to force my app to be moved to suspended state?

Comment: are you testing this while connected to Xcode?  When you run a debug build from Xcode your app is not suspended.

Comment: @Paulw11 No, it's not. I launch my app from home screen. It's related to the battery draining issue. You can try to upgrade to iOS 13.5.1 and go to the battery usage page. There will be many apps running in the background for several hours.

Comment: I have 13.5.1 on my phone. I just checked the battery usage and it looks pretty normal. A few apps with a few minutes background over the last 24 hours and a an hour or so usage over the last 10 days.

Comment: Here's the screenshot of my battery usage page. https://i.imgur.com/4XLx3De.jpg You can see there are two apps running in the background for several hours. It occurs randomly, the only way I know to reproduce this issue is to switch between foreground and background several times and play with it a little bit while.

Comment: This is the log file screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/6csMpGF.png As you can see there's a `App enters background` line which represents the app is in background state. But it's still running in the background. After 2.5 seconds I set my app into a nap state to save battery life. It keeps running for almost an hour.

Answer (score 1):

We're seeing this in our app too. The only solution we've found so far is to manually stop things that were running on a timer/schedule that normally would have just been handled by the app being suspended by the OS. Hoping Apple releases a fix for this soon...

Comment: But it's not possible to stop things which were started by third-party libraries like AdMob or Facebook Audience Network. So the CPU usage won't be zero.

Comment: I have noticed this too - timing aligns exactly with the release of 13.5.1.  NSTimer keeps running in background and continues to execute network calls that were suspended prior to 13.5.1

Comment: It appears that IOS 13.6 has fixed this problem.  The timer seems to fire one additional time after the app goes into the background, but then stops.